# SQLite: How to combine two triggers into one if operation are the same?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, android-sqlite, database-trigger

I have two triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerAfterInsert AFTER INSERT ON ...  SQL_STATEMENT1 
CREATE TRIGGER triggerAfterUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON ...  SQL_STATEMENT1
```

Obviously the different is just INSERT and UPDATE, as the triggered SQL_STATEMENT1 is the same for both. Is there a way for me to combine them into a single Trigger where both INSERT and UPDATE will trigger it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), you cannot have two different operations (INSERT, UDPATE) for the same trigger.

Comment: Thanks! Noted. Seems like on SQL, it can be cone using INSERT OR UPDATE, but not SQLite.

Comment: Also in http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/ , it is stated `Suppose you use a UPDATE statement to update 10 rows in a table, the trigger that associated with the table is fired 10 times`. Expensive operation after update.